# CoreCLR: DefaultDomain error when running application on visual studio 19/22

Tags: c#, .net, dll

This are the errors I get when I try to run the services, the console window just flashes, opens and close same time.

The projects targets .NET Core 2.1 which is installed on the machine and I can locate it in **C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App**.

But the error I get when running seems like VS targets .net 2.2.0

> output 'Kyc.Server.Service.Profile.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain):
> Loaded 'C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.0\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'.
> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll The program '[25324]
> Kyc.Server.Service.Profile.exe' has exited with code 2147516553
> (0x80008089).

[See basic console app created with .Net Core 2.1 which this error occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlQia.png)

Comment: That is CoreClrInitFailure, it could not get the CLR initialized.  Usually has something to do with a bad .NET install, that ArgumentException is an attractive debugging target.  But as long as we can't see a stack trace, the logical way ahead is to retarget to 6.0

Comment: I have updated the post with a link to a screenshot to produces this error, please have a look